# General error when starting new container

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

Not sure where to post general error questions for Bluemix Containers such as this one:

```
Error response from daemon: {
  "code": "IC5000E",
  "description": "Sorry, an error occurred on our side. Please reference the problem using the provided incident ID",
  "incident_id": "b241118fba37fe03",
  "name": "DefaultError",
  "rc": "500",
  "type": "General"
}
```

The docker containers works just fine when running it in my Digital Ocean droplet (standard Ubuntu server with docker 1.7.0).
Get the same error using cf ic, docker and also get a general error when trying to start Bluemix web-UI.

Comment: Can you detail the steps you used to push and start the container on the platform?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it turns out that the error was the following:

```
 --env MQTT_URL="mqtt://somehost.example.org:1883"
```

This used to work running it against Bluemix, but now it gives the general error, it works when running it "locally" using docker 1.7.0

The double-quote has to enclose the whole environment like this:

```
  -e "MQTT_URL=mqtt://somehost.example.org:1883"
```

The only thing worth mentioning in addition to this is that the following syntax did NOT work:

```
--env "key1=val2 key2=val2"
```

That is how it should be according to the [docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_single_cli)

> -e ENV, --env ENV
>
> (Optional) Set a number of environment variables where ENV is a key=value pair.
>
> List multiple keys in quotation marks and separate them with spaces.
>
> Example: -e "key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3"

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will open a work item to get the documentation updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a support ticket at http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and report the error and all details you have to provide.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed -e "key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3" is wrong syntax. The right syntax is -e key1=value1 -e key2=value2 -e key3=value3